# How to use protractor to verify if two spans are equal in different locations?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, selenium-webdriver, protractor

```
<span ng-bind="locations.selectedCount" class="ng-binding">1005</span>

<span ng-bind="locations.selectedCount" class="ng-binding">1005</span>
```

How would I verify through protractor that the value of these two spans are the same when one span is under an  tag while the other is under a label tag in different places?

is it using the 'equal' element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A straight-forward option would be to find both spans and compare the texts:

```
var firstSpan = element(by.css("a.showld")).element(by.binding("locations.selectedCount")),
    secondSpan = element(by.css('label[key="search.selectedLocations"]')).element(by.binding("locations.selectedCount"));

firstSpan.getText().then(function (firstText) {
    var secondText = secondSpan.getText();
    expect(secondText).toEqual(firstText);
});
```

Note that `getText()`, as many other methods in `Protractor`, returns a promise which needs to be resolved. We have two promises here, the resolved values of which we need to compare, we are resolving the first one explicitly via `then()` and letting `expect()` to implicitly resolve the second. See more at: [Comparing values of two promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28559864/comparing-values-of-two-promises).

Another possible approach:

```
var spans = element.all(by.binding("locations.selectedCount"));
spans.first().getText().then(function (firstText) {
    var lastText = spans.last().getText();
    expect(lastText).toEqual(firstText);
});
```

This is though not quite scalable and is good probably for 2 elements only.

---

A more scalable solution would involve using [`map()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map) and [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). Let's gather all the `span` texts into a array and check if [all the items in the array are equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14832603/check-if-all-values-of-array-are-equal):

```
var spans = element.all(by.binding("locations.selectedCount"));

spans.map(function (span) {
    return span.getText();
}).then(function (texts) {
    var allTextsAreTheSame = texts.reduce(function(a, b) {
        return (a === b) ? a: false;
    });
    expect(allTextsAreTheSame).toBe(true);
});
```

Comment: @Kisuna97 ok, I've provided you with 3 options, try them out and let me know.

Comment: your 2nd approach, i get an error expected 1023 to equal to ' ' 
and for the last approach it worked after i changed a: false; to a: true;

Comment: @Kisuna97 don't change `false` to `true` in the third approach. Can you check how many `span` elements with this binding are there on the page? And also, what about the first option? (I'll be AFK for a while, but it sounds like you have more than one `span` element with the same `locations.selectedCount` binding, probably others are invisible..check it out). Thanks.

Comment: the first one I understand the code, however it says no element found using by.binding(locations.selectedCount)

Comment: @Kisuna97 well, can you provide a link to the website or an HTML code of the appropriate block? Also, do you see any iframes on the page? Thanks.

Comment: @Kisuna97 now I'm puzzled what your real HTML is and what are you trying to achieve. Anyway, I think you should be able to adapt any of the 3 options I've provided.